# Methods for a lengthy nonlinear equation

Tags: logarithms, roots

I want to solve the following equation without plugging into a computer, and get an answer in terms of functions rather than a decimal output.

$$-\dfrac{\sqrt{2}\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{2x}{3}\right)^{\frac{2x}{3}-\frac{1}{4}}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{x}{3}\right)^{\frac{x}{3}-\frac{1}{2}}\left(3\ln\left(x\right)-\ln\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{x}{3}\right)-2\ln\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{2x}{3}\right)\right)}{3x^x}=0$$
where $x>0$.

I understand that this is quite a tedious equation to solve, and I am not looking for a complete answer, but rather suggestions as to how I can approach this. I see that we can use logarithm properties in the numerator, and completely disregard the denominator. However, I am not sure what to do with the $x$'s in the exponents. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you work in the real domain, you should notice that you need to limit the range to $0 < x < \frac 38$, the bounds corresponding to vertical asymptotes.

Then, you can rewrite the expression as 
$$\frac{1}{3} \sqrt{2} \left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{2 x}{3}\right)^{\frac{2
   x}{3}-\frac{1}{4}}
   \left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{x}{3}\right)^{\frac{x}{3}-\frac{1}{2}} x^{-x} \log
   \left(\frac{x^3}{\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{2 x}{3}\right)^2
   \left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{x}{3}\right)}\right)=0$$ and, as you wrote, one of the solution will correspond to 
$$\frac{x^3}{\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{2 x}{3}\right)^2
   \left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{x}{3}\right)}=1$$ that is to say $$x^3=\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{2 x}{3}\right)^2
   \left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{x}{3}\right) \implies \frac{31 x^3}{27}-\frac{x^2}{3}+\frac{3 x}{16}-\frac{1}{32}=0$$ which is a cubic with only one real root that you can compute using Cardano's method or Newton starting for example at $x_0=\frac 3 {16}$ (mid point of the definition interval).

Newton iterates would just be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.1875000000 \\
 1 & 0.1888297872 \\
 2 & 0.1888267763
\end{array}
\right)$$

If you prefer Cardano, the root would be given by
$$x=\frac{3}{124} \left(4-\frac{77}{\sqrt[3]{467+93 \sqrt{78}}}+\sqrt[3]{467+93
   \sqrt{78}}\right)$$ This is the only solution to the problem.

More fancy would be 
$$x=\frac{3}{62} \left(2+\sqrt{77} \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{467}{77 \sqrt{77}}\right)\right)\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint about the parts you seem worried about:

$a^b=0$ if and only if $a=0$ and $b>0$. If $b<0$ you have general problems elsewhere (so you should probably stipulate that $x\geq 3/2$) and if $b=0$ you run into a bit of a jam at $a=0$, so strict inequality would be nice there.

Comment: Could I also set the expression inside the $\ln$ equal to $1$?

Comment: @高田航 Yes; once you've turned it into $\ln(f(x))$ for some function of $f$, it suffices to find $x$ where $f(x)=1$.